# fixed menu not working

Tags: html, css

I want my menu to stay on its place while I scroll, but when I add the following in my CSS`position:fixed;` the whole thing goes out of the place from where I want it to be.

In this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mvmbtcby/) you can see how it is now and how I want it to be. The only thing wrong with it, is that if I change the position to fixed it doesn't stay where I want it to be anymore.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>random</title>
  <!--   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css"> -->

</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="headcontainer">
        </div>
               <div id="menu">
                <div id="logo">
                    <p>
                        Hier komt een logo
                    </p>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        Home
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Over
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Contact
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Producte
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

<div id="content">
<div class="text-box">


    </div>
    <div class="text-box">


    </div>
</div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>

<style>
    /*Global*/

    * {
        margin: 0px;
    }

    body {}

    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6 {}

    h1 {}

    h2 {}

    h3 {}

    h4 {}

    a {}

    img {}

    #container {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 100%;

    }

    #headcontainer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: pink;

    }
    /* navigation */

    #menu {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1);
        max-height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-top: none;


    }

    #menu li {
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-left: 20px;
        position: relative;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }

    #menu ul {
        float:right;
        height:100%;
        width: auto;
        line-height: 100px;
        margin-right:25px;
    }

    #menu ul li {

    }

    #menu ul li:hover {
        cursor:pointer;
        color: white;
    }

    #logo {
        height: 50px;
        width: auto;
        background-color: red;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-left: 60px;


    }

    /*content*/
    #content {
    width:100%;
    height:1000px;
    min-height:500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;


    }

    .text-box {
    width:40%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:blue;
    min-height:100px;
    float:left;
margin-left:5%;
margin-right:5%;
margin-top:50px;
    }

    </style>
```

EDIT:
I'm trying to achieve something like this:

http://themes.lucky-roo.com/resume-cv/berg-v1.7/HTML_Template/home-1-static-image.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, i see what you want and i think you will code this behaviour in Javascript.

This kind of solution will be okay for you ??

Démo : http://jsfiddle.net/cc48t

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
         $('#scroller').css('top', $(window).scrollTop());
    }
}
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use menu inside the headercontainor and give     position: fixed; fom #menu

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <title>random</title>
      <!--   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css"> -->
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="headcontainer">
      
      <div id="menu">
                    <div id="logo">
                        <p>
                            Hier komt een logo
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Home
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Over
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Contact
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Producte
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
       
            </div>
                   
    
    <div id="content">
    <div class="text-box">
    
    
        </div>
        <div class="text-box">
    
    
        </div>
    </div>
    
        </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
    
    <style>
        /*Global*/
    
        * {
            margin: 0px;
        }
    
        body {}
    
        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        h4,
        h5,
        h6 {}
    
        h1 {}
    
        h2 {}
    
        h3 {}
    
        h4 {}
    
        a {}
    
        img {}
    
        #container {
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 100%;
    
        }
    
        #headcontainer {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: pink;
    
        }
        /* navigation */
    
        #menu {
                position: fixed;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1);
            max-height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-top: none;
    
    
        }
    
        #menu li {
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding-left: 20px;
            position: relative;
            padding-right: 20px;
        }
    
        #menu ul {
            float:right;
            height:100%;
            width: auto;
            line-height: 100px;
            margin-right:25px;
        }
    
        #menu ul li {
    
        }
    
        #menu ul li:hover {
            cursor:pointer;
            color: white;
        }
    
        #logo {
            height: 50px;
            width: auto;
            background-color: red;
            float: left;
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-top: 30px;
            margin-left: 60px;
    
    
        }
    
        /*content*/
        #content {
        width:100%;
        height:1000px;
        min-height:500px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    
    
        }
    
        .text-box {
        width:40%;
        height:auto;
        background-color:blue;
        min-height:100px;
        float:left;
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-right:5%;
    margin-top:50px;
        }
    
        </style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are not using JQuery, You can achieve it through the simple javascript

```js
var header             = document.querySelector('div'),
     title              = header.querySelector('ul'),
    fix_class          = 'fixnav';

function stickyScroll(e) {

  if( window.pageYOffset > 310 ) {
    title.classList.add(fix_class);
  }

  if( window.pageYOffset < 310 ) {
    title.classList.remove(fix_class);
  }
}

// Scroll handler to toggle classes.
window.addEventListener('scroll', stickyScroll, false);
```

```css
<style>
    /*Global*/
    
    * {
        margin: 0px;
    }
    
    body {}
    
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6 {}
    
    h1 {}

    h2 {}
    
    h3 {}
    
    h4 {}
    
    a {}
    
    img {}
    
    #container {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 100%;
      
    }
    
    #headcontainer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: pink;

    }
    /* navigation */
    .fixnav{
      position:fixed;
      z-index:9999;
      top:0;
    }
    #menu {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1);
        max-height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-top: none;
        transition: 1s all;
    }
    
    #menu li {
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-left: 20px;
        position: relative;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
    
    #menu ul {
        float:right;
        height:100%;
        width: auto;
        line-height: 100px;
        margin-right:25px;
    }
    
    #menu ul li {

    }
    
    #menu ul li:hover {
        cursor:pointer;
        color: white;
    }
    
    #logo {
        height: 50px;
        width: auto;
        background-color: red;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-left: 60px;
        

    }

    /*content*/
    #content {
 width:100%;
 height:1000px;
 min-height:500px;
 margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    

    }

    .text-box {
 width:40%;
 height:auto;
 background-color:blue;
 min-height:100px;
 float:left;
margin-left:5%;
margin-right:5%;
margin-top:50px;
    }

    </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>random</title>
  <!--   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css"> -->
    
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="headcontainer">
        </div>
               <div id="menu">
                <div id="logo">
                    <p>
                        Hier komt een logo
                    </p>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        Home
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Over
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Contact
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Producte
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    
<div id="content">
<div class="text-box">


 </div>
 <div class="text-box">


 </div>
</div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sank8893/mvmbtcby/3/

Answer (score 2):

Add the following script it will work fine

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 650) {
            $('#menu').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0');
        } else {
            $('#menu').css('position', 'static');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but if i add top:0; the menu goes to the top and i want it after the pink bg. –

Answer (score 2):

I create a jsfiddle.

I just add those lines in #menu and it works for me:

```
    position : fixed;
    top: 0;
```

The menu doesn't move.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but if i add top:0; the menu goes to the top and i want it after the pink bg.

Comment: Ok, i see what you want and i think you will code this behaviour in Javascript.

Comment: Yes, Thanks  a lot!

Comment: can you make a new post with the new solution then i will accept

Comment: Done ! ;)

Good to hear that !

Answer (score 2):

Add these styles to your menu in css
.

```
position: fixed
top:0
```

The combination of these 2 will make sure the menu stays where it has to stay : always at the top.

As @Error404 said:

> the fixed elements goes out of the normal flow of the document and this
>   is why you can position it on the top of the screen.

Comment: An answer without an explanation should not be an answer.

Comment: @Error404 Better ?

Comment: I would add that the fixed elements goes out of the normal flow of the document and it is why you can position it on the top of the screen.

Comment: You're right, I've editited again to be more completed

Answer (score 2):

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(window).scroll(function () {
  //if you hard code, then use console
  //.log to determine when you want the 
  //nav bar to stick.  
  console.log($(window).scrollTop())
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
  $('#nav_bar').addClass('navbar-fixed');
}
if ($(window).scrollTop() < 100) {
  $('#nav_bar').removeClass('navbar-fixed');
}
 });
});
```

Css:

```
.navbar-fixed{
  position:fixed;
    z-index:auto;
    Top:0px;
}
```

Since you need this css to be appended only when you have scrolled a certain height in your webpage, Using this js code you can append navbar-fixed class to menu div after scrolling a certain amount of height.